# Django - Common Cleaning Data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have one model, and 3 different forms that use this model (of course, each form have different fields of this model). I wrote several **clean** function to valid the form fill... But, I really dont want copy and past this validation to all forms.

Is it possible to have one common cleaning class? How can I call it?

Here is the actual code:

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):      

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    cpf = models.CharField('CPF', max_length=14, blank=True)
    cnpj = models.CharField('CNPJ', max_length=18, blank=True)
```

...

forms.py

```
 class yyyyyForm(UserCreationForm):  
           ...
           def Meta:
              ...
           def Save:
              ...
           def clean_cpf(self):
              ...

class xxxxxForm(UserCreationForm):  
   ...
   def Meta:
      ...
   def Save:
      ...
   def clean_cpf(self):
      ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you have one baseForm class where you put the clean_cpf() method and then extend that for the other forms, and since clean_cpf is in the parent form, you shouldn't have to implement it in the child classes.

In your example it looks like you have a base class called UserCreationForm if that is your form that you can edit then you can put your clean method there.

Comment: Thanks, for sure this is the best idea. I got an example from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1228/ but your idea is much better.